# JavaFX: scale ImageView to table column width

Tags: javafx, imageview, width, html-table, scale

I display images within a table column. To scale the image I use

```
    image.fitWidthProperty().bind(col.widthProperty().subtract(40));
```

But I need a solution to scale only, if the image width is bigger than the column width. In the other case, I'll use the original image width.

How I can write that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the image has loaded, you can get its width by calling `getWidth()` on the `Image` (not on the `ImageView`).

Then you can do

```
image.fitWidthProperty().bind(
    Bindings.when(col.widthProperty().lessThan(imageWidth + 40))
            .then(col.widthProperty().subtract(40))
            .otherwise(imageWidth));
```